# Unknown Syntax Error in google aiy voice kit code

Tags: python, google-aiy

When running the following code there is a syntax error. I have researched and the syntax error happens for no reason that I know. The syntax error is: File "src/cloudspeech_demo.py", line 49 elif 'repeat after me' in text:
 TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation    ^

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# Copyright 2017 Google Inc.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""A demo of the Google CloudSpeech recognizer."""

import aiy.audio
import aiy.cloudspeech
import aiy.voicehat


def main():
    recognizer = aiy.cloudspeech.get_recognizer()
    recognizer.expect_phrase('turn off the light')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('turn on the light')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('blink')
    recognizer.expect_phrase('repeat after me')

    button = aiy.voicehat.get_button()
    led = aiy.voicehat.get_led()
    aiy.audio.get_recorder().start()

    while True:
        print('Press the button and speak')
        button.wait_for_press()
        print('Listening...')
        text = recognizer.recognize()
        if text is None:
            print('Sorry, I did not hear you.')
        else:
            print('You said "', text, '"')
            if 'turn on the light' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.ON)
            elif 'turn off the light' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.OFF)
            elif 'blink' in text:
                led.set_state(aiy.voicehat.LED.BLINK)
            elif 'repeat after me' in text:
                to_repeat = text.replace('repeat after me', '', 1)
                aiy.audio.say(to_repeat)
            elif 'goodbye' in text:
                break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please tell me what I need to do to fix this error.

Comment: You came to SO for a single parenthesis?

Comment: Looks like it...

Comment: I fixed that but when i run it it comes back the the same syntax error: File "src/cloudspeech_demo.py", line 47 elif 'repeat after me' in text: ^ TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Did you consider reexamining your use of tabs and spaces in indentation?

Comment: What do you mean by that

Comment: You probably need to replace any tabs you used with spaces. Depending on how you are editing your code, you may have a problem with spaces vs tabs. If you are using sudo nano, you will definitely need to use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
to_repeat = text.replace9'repeat after me', '', 1)
```

to

```
to_repeat = text.replace('repeat after me', '', 1)
```

You accidentally typed a `9` instead of a `(`, which makes sense since they are on the same key. You probably forgot to click shift.

Comment: Yes I fixed that but when i run it it comes back the the same syntax error: File "src/cloudspeech_demo.py", line 47
    elif 'repeat after me' in text:
                                                ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Comment: Not for me 